# PC monitors show black margins on top, right, bottom and left sides

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

I bought two Insignia (Best Buy brand) 24" monitors.  Because my computer didn't have dual ports coming out of the video card, I then bought a Radeon AMD graphics video card.  Because the computer industry is messed up and is so greedy, they have one VGA port, one HDMI port and one DVI port, to force consumers to buy an adapter for dual display.  So I bought the adaptor (link below) and plugged my monitors into that.  Both cables are HDMI.  So now one is going into the HDMI video card port and one into the DVI video card port.

**Insignia 24" monitors:**

http://www.insigniaproducts.com/products/computer-speakers-accessories/NS-24EM51A14.html

**HDMI to DVI Adapter:**

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009YCASK2/ref=oh_details_o05_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009YCASK2)

I thought I increased the resolution to the max within Windows 8.  Windows is set at 1920x1080 under the screen resolution settings.  And the video card properties said it's maximum resolution is 1920x1080.  The monitor link above says that it supports 1920x1080.

So why do I have a 3/4" margin at the top and bottom of each monitor display, and a 1 1/4" margin on the left and right sides of each monitor display?  Meaning it's just black on those margins.

***What could be causing the black margins?  Do I need a different video card, different monitors or are my cables not supporting the resolution?***

**Screen shot of video card settings:**

[image]

**Screen shot of Windows 8 resolution settings (when focused on monitor "2"):**

[image]

**Screen shot of Windows 8 resolution settings (when focused on monitor "3"):**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I found this article.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01775596#N92

Had to go into the "Catalyst Control Center", then selected the "HDTV Support (Digital Flat-Panel)", and then selected each display (ie: NS-24EM51A14) and dragged the slider to the far right (Overscan) or to 0%.  0% gives 0 margins.  15% gives huge margins.  It was set in the middle by default upon installation.

[image]

[image]